# In bash script, for a string of characters (English word), how do count the number of occurrences of that word in an external text file?

Tags: string, bash, search

For example: Suppose the keyword is "apple" and the text file you're searching through for the word "apple" is called fruits.txt.

Now, suppose fruits.txt is a text file that contains an essay on fruits (i.e., it's not a list; it's in paragraph form) and you're interested in the number of times the word "apple" comes up ("Apple", "ApPlE", "APPLE", etc... all permutations of character cases of the word "apple" is considered to be equivalent to "apple" and thus counts as an occurrence).

What is one way you can do this is a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty easy...

**fruits.txt**

```
apple
APPLE
AppLe

This is a sentence that has the word AppLe in is. That is contained
in a paragraph within the document.
```

**countApples.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 

grep -c -i -w apple fruits.txt
```

This will print `4` to STDOUT as it will g(re)p the word `-w` apple while being case-insensitive `-i` and count `-c` the matches in the file `fruits.txt`

The important thing to note is that within a `BASH` script you are within your shell so you have all the tools in your shell available to your script. In this case we used [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

Comment: Wow! That's a very useful function! I'll have to try to incorporate grep into my toolbox.

Comment: Ah! I just tried that code in my script and it seems that grep will only return the number of lines on which the keyword appears, not necessarily the number of occurrences. 

In the following example, your command will also return 4 even though apple appears 6 times!

apple
APPLE
AppLe Apple APPLE

This is a sentence that has the word AppLe in is. That is contained
in a paragraph within the document.

Comment: Sorry formatting screwed up the example. Basically, Apple appears 6 times in the text (it is repeated on a single line but grep discounts this).

Comment: Oh I just realized I can basically take what grep gives me and feed it through a for loop to count the number of times the keyword appears. If there is a quicker way, please let me know!

Comment: Try `grep -o -i -w fruits.txt | wc -l`. The `-o` has grep print out each match on a new line, and `wc -l` counts the number of lines.

Comment: Ack - another stipulation!

It turns out that the above would omit words like "apple," and "Apples." and "Apples/Oranges" which aren't technically "apple" but I would consider them to be. How do I capture those words? (So something like the form %apple% where % is allowed to be /,.-+=